# tkinter wait for button press with .invoke()

Tags: python, button, tkinter, invoke

```
import time
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, BOTH
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button
from tkinter import *


def playFile(filePath, interval = 5, playTime = 60):
    playCount = int(playTime//interval)
    for play in range(0, playCount):
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load(filePath)
        mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(interval*60)

global clicked
clicked = False


def findFile():
    global clicked
    clicked = True
    fileLocation = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("mp3 files","*.mp3"), ("m4a files", ".m4a"), ("all files","*.*")))
    return fileLocation


file = ''


class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Interval Player")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = 1)

        openButton = Button(self, text = "Open", command=findFile)
        openButton.place(x=0, y=0)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    if clicked == True:
            file = str(openButton.invoke())
            playFile(file)      
    app = Example()   
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I choose to invoke the results of the button, the file explorer window opens before openButton has been clicked. How do I make the program wait for button press before invoking the value from the button?

I have tried using a global variable with True/False to find if the button has been clicked. However, I feel like the program is not repeatedly checking for this boolean. Maybe there is a specific function where the playFile has to be added?

Comment: You seem to be making this vastly more complicated than it needs to be.  Just have your `findFile()` call `playFile()` directly; no need for globals, or for whatever you think `.invoke()` is doing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code

```
if clicked == True:
            file = str(openButton.invoke())
            playFile(file)
```

is never used.

what you need to do is act after the message box popup

therefore

```
def findFile():
    global clicked
    clicked = True
    fileLocation = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("mp3 files","*.mp3"), ("m4a files", ".m4a"), ("all files","*.*")))
    return fileLocation
```

becomes

```
def findFile():
    global clicked
    clicked = True
    fileLocation = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("mp3 files","*.mp3"), ("m4a files", ".m4a"), ("all files","*.*")))
    if fileLocation:
          playFile(fileLocation)
    return fileLocation
```

Full working example

```
import time
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, BOTH
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button
from tkinter import *


def playFile(filePath, interval = 5, playTime = 60):
    playCount = int(playTime//interval)
    for play in range(0, playCount):
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load(filePath)
        mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(interval*60)

global clicked
clicked = False


def findFile():
    global clicked
    clicked = True
    fileLocation = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("mp3 files","*.mp3"), ("m4a files", ".m4a"), ("all files","*.*")))
    playFile(fileLocation)
    return fileLocation


file = ''


class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Interval Player")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = 1)

        openButton = Button(self, text = "Open", command=findFile)
        openButton.place(x=0, y=0)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```